# Convert to Python List type variable from MATLAB code? Type convert error : List list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, matlab, type-conversion

MATLAB

```matlab
BS = {};
Ksize = 2;
[value,index] = max(BSpar(:));
[r, c] = find(BSpar == value);

    for i = 1:K
            for j=1:K
                block =BS{r,c}((i-1)*Ksize+1:i*Ksize,(j-1)*Ksize+1:j*Ksize);
```

Python

```py
BS = [];
Ksize = 2;
value = max(np.ravel(BSpar))
r, c= find(BSpar == value, nargout=2)
for i in range(K):
    for j in range(K):
        block = BS[r,c][i * Ksize:(i+1)*Ksize, j * Ksize:(j + 1) * Ksize]
```

Error:

> List indices must be integer or slices , not tuple.

Comment: If `BS` is a python list, you cannot use `BS[r,c]`. You may do something like `BS[r][c]` instead (if the indices are valid)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing the code + error message, but also a textual description on what the code is supposed to do, and what it currently does, see [mcve]. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. Please [edit] the question accordingly.